# ansible: 'A worker was found in a dead state' : python exit's SIGABRT when using python .net in an ansible task

Tags: python, .net, ansible, python.net

i am trying to use a .net C# code in Python / [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/)  . The goal of the C# code is to download large files (100mb) and store them localy.

When i ran the implemented Python code in a local test it is working!
But if i run the code via ansible the following error is thrown

- **error! A worker was found in a dead state**

[System-Overview for better understanding][1]

```
from pythonnet import load
load("coreclr")
import clr

clr.AddReference("yyyyyy.yyyy.yyy")

.....

def doWork(self, x, xx, feedUrl, xxx, xxxx):
          
        from xxxxx import Repository, PackageId, PackageVersion
        from System import Uri, Exception
       
     
        feedUri = Uri(str(feedUrl))           
        pi = PackageId(str(x))
        pv = PackageVersion(str(xx))

        repo = Repository(feedUri,str(xxx), "", str(xxxx))
       
        info= repo.GetPackage(pi, pv)
     
        return info
```

[ansible code where Error is thrown](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/e38b3e64fd5f9bb6c5ca9462150c89f0932fd2c4/lib/ansible/plugins/strategy/__init__.py#L799)

### Question:

As described above the logic/python-code is working in an python test. When running the same python-code with ansible, something is different.

- So why is the workerprocess closed with 'exitcode=-SIGABRT'
- Whatis the difference between test code execution and ansible code execution?
- What can i do to track the error down?

### Environment

- virtual machine Ubuntu 22.04
- 12 gb ram

### What i tried so far:

1. make C# code strict sync
2. C# debug code:
   I added debug code to the C# class and tracked the  error down to the

   `var response = httpClient.Send(request);`
3. add debug code to ansible ([task_queue_manager](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/f1ded0f41759235eb15a7d13dbc3c95dce5d5acd/lib/ansible/executor/task_queue_manager.py#L406))

   with this code i get the error detail:

   `worker: <WorkerProcess name='WorkerProcess-15' pid=16145 parent=16069 stopped exitcode=-SIGABRT>`
4. increasing ram / watching ram

   when watching the ram (via htop) there is nothing suspicious,
   from my point of view

---

**Edit:**

here are the things i found out today!

1. the http request done by the httpclient gets terminated witha 'TCP Zero Window' message  [what is TCP Zero Window](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/wireshark-tcp-zero-window/#What%20Is%20TCP%20Zero%20window?) means the client is not/ slow processing the data
2. i tried to rebuild the ansible code in my test and i was able to reproduce the issue. It seems that the issue is related to the Python [Process/multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)
   Thread code works
   Process code does not work.

```
            thread = threading.Thread(target = self.DoWork)
            thread.start()
            thread.join()
    
            p = Process(target=self.DoWork)
            p.start()
            p.join()
```

since ansible is using processes [link](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/f1ded0f41759235eb15a7d13dbc3c95dce5d5acd/lib/ansible/executor/process/worker.py#L49) i still do not know what the problem is.

Comment: I don't understand how is this question related to Ansible. Also, the need to use C# to download the files is also unclear. Could you please edit you question and add more details on your setup and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev we have the same download logic in C# and Python, so we don't  want to have this dublicated. 
I added a system overview , whitch i hope make it clear how i test and use the ansible

Comment: Thanks for the details. But unfortunately they still didn't help to understand - why do you need to 1) duplicate the functionality that Ansible [has out-of-the-box](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html) and doesn't require testing 2) in C# 3) in C# on a Linux server?